# Retrieve List of networks for a subscription in windows azure with azure java sdk

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net, azure-java-sdk

How to Retrieve List of networks for a subscription in windows azure  with azure sdk?

Answer (score 0):

There's a test in SDK that does this:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/management-network/src/test/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/network/NetworkOperationsTests.java#L104